# Spring Boot Repository JUnit Repository test - Issue of verify method (Cannot work)

Tags: spring-boot, junit, repository

What I just want to ask is to learn how we can use "verify" in these 2 methods.
I added its usage to each method but I'm not sure whether it is right.
I cannot handle with this process.

How can I solve it out?

Which is the best way to define verify in JUnit test method.

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
@DataJpaTest
public class EmployeeRespositoryTests {

private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {

    employeeRepository = mock(EmployeeRepository.class);
}

@Test
    public void givenEmployeeObject_whenSave_thenReturnSavedEmployee(){

        //given - precondition or setup
        Employee employee = Employee.builder()
                .firstName("Name 1")
                .lastName("Surname 1")
                .email("user1@a,com")
                .build();
        // when - action or the behaviour that we are going test
        Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);

        // then - verify the output
        assertThat(savedEmployee).isNotNull();
        assertThat(savedEmployee.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);

        // HERE IS MY CODE
        verify(employeeRepository, times(1)).save(user);
    }


    // JUnit test for get all employees operation
    @DisplayName("JUnit test for get all employees operation")
    @Test
    public void givenEmployeesList_whenFindAll_thenEmployeesList(){
        // given - precondition or setup
        Employee employee = Employee.builder()
                .firstName("Name 1")
                .lastName("Surname 1")
                .email("user1@a,com")
                .build();

        Employee employee1 = Employee.builder()
                .firstName("Name 2")
                .lastName("Surname 2")
                .email("user2@a,com")
                .build();

        employeeRepository.save(employee);
        employeeRepository.save(employee1);

        // when -  action or the behaviour that we are going test
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepository.findAll();

        // then - verify the output
        assertThat(employeeList).isNotNull();
        assertThat(employeeList.size()).isEqualTo(2);

        verify(employeeRepository, times(2)).save(user);
        verify(employeeRepository, times(1)).findAll();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify is not appropriate in either case here as you are explicitly calling the methods you want to verify in your test.

Usual reason for verify would be to check if a method on a mock dependency in your method under test had been called with the correct arguments

Example

```
public class Calculator {

    private Adder adder;

    public Calculator(Adder adder) {
        this.adder = adder;
    }

    public int addNumbers(int a, int b) {
        return adder.add(a, b);
    }
}

public class Adder {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class CalculatorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Calculator calculator;

    @Mock
    private Adder adder;

    @Test
    public void addOneAndThreeReturnsFour() {
        when(adder.add(1, 3)).thenReturn(4);

        assertEquals(4, calculator.addNumbers(1, 3));

        verify(adder).add(1, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I editted my post to add repository as a mock. Is it right?

Comment: I have added an example to show use of verify that add(1, 3) method has been called on the mock adder.

Comment: How can I use when and verify in RepositoryTest if possible?

Comment: You can't. Verify is only used on mocks and you can't/shouldn't mock the class you are testing

Comment: You mean it can be used in ServiceTest

Comment: Yes, in your service test you can mock your repository and verify the behaviour